# KVC without NSObject (NSPredicate)

Tags: swift, nspredicate, nsobject, key-value-coding, kvc

I'm trying to use NSPredicate like so:

```
let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(username BEGINSWITH[c] $word)")

    if prefix == "@" {
        if countElements(word) > 0 {
            suggestionDatasource.users = (suggestionDatasource.users as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(namePredicate!.predicateWithSubstitutionVariables(["word" : word])) as [User]
        }
    }
```

However, my User class doesn't subclass NSObject so it's not Key Value Compliant. I get `unrecognized selector 'valueForKey'` whenever I try this. Is there a way I can make a custom class Key Value Compliant without subclassing NSObject? Or perhaps a way to use NSPredicate without having to use KVC.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use `filter` and forget about NSPredicate (and NSArray)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you making this awfully unnecessarily hard for yourself? Why not just use what Swift gives you - `filter`, `hasPrefix`, and so on? I don't know what a User actually is, but let's pretend it's something like this:

```
struct User {
    let username : String = ""
}
```

And let's pretend that `users` is like this:

```
let users = [User(username:"Matt Neuburg"), User(username:"Dudley Doright")]
```

Then what you seem to be trying to do is *trivial* in Swift:

```
let word = "Matt"
let users2 = users.filter {$0.username.hasPrefix(word)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually implement `value(forKey key: String) -> Any?` method:

```
extension Model {
    @objc func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        switch key {
        case "id":
            return id
        // Other fields
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Note `@objc` prefix of the method: it's important, as it's allowing `NSPredicate` to see that the method is implemented.